Transferred Enrollment Agent Certificate not showing when Enrolling
I have issued myself an enrollment agent certificate from my CA on COMPUTER1. I have used this certificate to enroll for certificates on behalf of others. I work in other areas, and we got network connection to my second location. I exported the Enrollment Agent certificate from COMPUTER1 and imported it to the Personal Store of the machine on COMPUTER2. This shows as installed in the store just as it does on COMPUTER1. When I go to enroll on behalf with my same credentials as COMPUTER1, when I get to the Select Enrollment Agent certificate it finds, NO certificates on COMPUTER2 even though it shows up in the store.
Does anyone know how to fix this or do I need to issue myself an Enrollment Certificate on COMPUTER2 as well?

Did you export enrollment agent certificate with private key? This should be in .pfx format. If it is .cer, then your exported public certificate only, without private key. You will have to re-export enrollment certificate with private key again.

@Crypt32 I can't export it as a .pfx because exported the private key is greyed out. This is on a Microsoft CA environment. I can't allow it to be exported in the template either as that option is also greyed out.

Based on your comments it sounds like the private key is protected. This is probably set in the enrollment template to prevent exporting the private key.
The easiest solution would be to enroll a second certificate for the second computer.

Thanks for the information. Since the cert is tied to the user on COMPUTER1 and not the COMPUTER I figured I could transfer it.

If you modify the certificate template to allow private key export, you could export the key in the future. However, generating a new cert is probably better security practice.
